# Symfony - Doctrine getResult() VS toIterable()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 4.4 and PHP 7.4. My doctrine version is 2.7.

I would like to iterate over my database document. When I use `toIterable` my memory increases at each row. After about 15 min I have a memory_limit error.

```
$documents = $this->em->getRepository(Document::class)->getDocuments($spool)->getQuery()->toIterable();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
     dump(Helper::formatMemory(memory_get_usage()));
}
```

When I use `getResult`, I have exactly the same memory at each row. I would like to know how my getResult consumes less memory than the iterator.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the version of doctrine?

Comment: I added the version number, is 2.7.

Comment: There seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8410) prior to 2.8.2 with toIterable not releasing object memory

Comment: Do you clear your entity manager(`$em->clear()`) sometimes ? Otherwise flushed entities will still be tracked and you'll get performances / memory issues

Comment: Yes I am using `$em->clear()` and flush using modulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't change the version of Doctrine at the moment.

I found a work around :

```
public function getDocuments(Deployment $deployment): \Traversable
    {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

        $sql = '
            SELECT d.id
            FROM document d
            WHERE d.deployment_id = :deployment_id
            ';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)->executeQuery([
            'deployment_id' => $deployment->getId(),
        ]);

        return $stmt->iterateAssociative();
    }
```